# YUI 3 how to get / save uploaded files with uploadURL

Tags: php, yui, yui3

I use example from YUI3 Documentation (http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/uploader/uploader-multiple.html)
Here is new uploader created:

> ```
> var uploader = new Y.Uploader({width: "250px",
> height: "35px",
> multipleFiles: true,
> swfURL: "flashuploader.swf?t=" + Math.random(),
> uploadURL: "http://yuilibrary.com/sandbox/upload/",
> simLimit: 2,
> withCredentials: false
> });
> ```

Can someone help me with uploadURL? I create getfile.php

```
uploadURL: "http://<website>/share_location/getfile.php",
```

but how I can get files and write them to my location?

Answer (score -1):

You can download see file :yui\src\uploader\tests\manual\simpleupload.php